# should_receive in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, rspec, message, expectations

As far as I know, `should_receive` is applied only to mock objects. What I want is to check, if a certain Class (not object) received a certain message, like:

```
User.should_receive(:all).once
```

How do I do that?

UPD. Commonly, writing test for models and controllers we *can* write User.should_receive(:smth).once. But in my case I'm testing an arbitrary class from the lib folder, and somehow I always receive the following message:

```
<User( [fields] ) (class)> expected :all with (no args) once, but received it 0 times>
```

Any ideas on why is that so? A test somehow sees the User class, but can't check if it receives a message. Of course I've ten times checked that the User *is* actually getting a message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy:

```
User.should_receive(:all).once
```

> What I want is to check, if a certain Class (not object) received a certain message

A class *is* an object!

Comment: Thanks for answer, Jörg. I've updated the question with more details.